# Entity Framework Group By with Max Date and count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT  Tag , COUNT(*) , MAX(CreatedDate)
FROM    dbo.tblTags
GROUP BY Tag
```

Which outputs the following:

```
+-----------------+------------------+-------------------------+
|       Tag       | (No column name) |    (No column name)     |
+-----------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| a great tag     |                1 | 2015-04-01 18:30:31.623 |
| not a test      |                1 | 2015-04-01 17:46:09.360 |
| test            |                5 | 2015-04-01 18:13:17.920 |
| test2           |                1 | 2013-03-07 16:53:54.217 |
+-----------------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

I'm trying to replicate the output of that query using EntityFramework.

I have the following logic which works:

```
    var GroupedTags = Tags.GroupBy(c => c.Tag)
        .Select(g => new 
        { 
            name = g.Key, 
            count = g.Count(), 
            date = g.OrderByDescending(gt => gt.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate 
        })
        .OrderBy(c => c.name);
```

But takes horribly long to execute compared to the raw SQL query. Any suggestions on how to optimise my approach? It somehow feels wrong.

Comment: you can use something like LinqPad to see what the generated SQL is and tweak your linq to get something closer to what you want

Comment: also you can use `g.Max(x => x.CreatedDate)`

Comment: also also, try adding a `ToList()` to ensure it hits the database one time.

Comment: @DLeh, yeah, `Max()` should do the trick ;) I suggest you to post it as an answer.

Comment: I have added an answer. hope that helps

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want a max, use the `Max()` Linq method:

```
var GroupedTags = Tags.GroupBy(c => c.Tag)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        name = g.Key, 
        count = g.Count(), 
        date = g.Max(x => x.CreatedDate)
    })
    .OrderBy(c => c.name);
```

Comment: Of course. Max as there in Linq. Completly spaced on that. Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Min and Max both are giving me the max dates if I use this