# Filter out duplicate(based on selected columns) query results using lambda function

Tags: c#, mysql, lambda

I have a query that returns a set of rows with campaignIds, PublisherIds, creationDate etc. I want to remove all the rows that have the same campaignId and PublisherId and retrieve the first creationDate(simplified example).

Doing a groupBy will either show me only the campaignIds and publisherIds or if i include the creationDate it will not filter out anything as the creationDates are all different,

The best i can comeup with in SQL is:

```
SELECT activityType, uniqueUserId, publisherId, campaignId, nodeID
FROM
    (
    SELECT activityType , count(Id) EventCount, uniqueUserId, campaignId, publisherId, nodeID , creationDate
    FROM Eventlog 
    WHERE campaignId IN (1687,5872,1819) AND activityType = 'Load'
    GROUP BY activityType, uniqueUserId, publisherId, campaignId, nodeID, creationDate
    ) AS sub

GROUP BY activityType, uniqueUserId, publisherId, campaignId, nodeID
```

But this will not show the creationDate as it is not included in the group by

In short: I want to remove all the rows that have the same combination of camapignId and publisherId and other criteria. and i want this in lambda form.

My current lambda function is:

```
var test = eventsTotal.GroupBy(x => new { x.CampaignId, x.PublisherId, x.NodeId, x.UniqueUserId });
```

But this doesnt give me the creationDate i need
Atm i am thinking that the only way seems to be to sort it as a list and compare each item with all the other ones to see if its a duplicate
any help is appreciated

Comment: your outer select filter doest not contain `creationDate` if you add it, this will make it accessable

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your outer select statement is missing the `creationDate`. This means the creationDate wont be in the result set sent from the database to your application.

### Solution

```
SELECT activityType, uniqueUserId, publisherId, campaignId, nodeID, MIN(creationDate) --I added creationDate here.
FROM
    (
    SELECT activityType , count(Id) EventCount, uniqueUserId, campaignId, publisherId, nodeID , creationDate
    FROM Eventlog 
    WHERE campaignId IN (1687,5872,1819) AND activityType = 'Load'
    GROUP BY activityType, uniqueUserId, publisherId, campaignId, nodeID, creationDate
    ) AS sub

GROUP BY activityType, uniqueUserId, publisherId, campaignId, nodeID
```

Comment: If i include it i get all the results and i dont want that. I think thats why i am adding the creationDate atm in my code and trying to filter the "duplicates" out in the code. But i dont know how to do this properly. I need the first creationDate from all the duplicates

Comment: Ah i see, you have to use a min() or max() (decide which is more logical) on this, so it will filter out the other values, and it is not grouped uppon

Comment: Ok i will try this. Is there anyway to use this in the lambda function? i am trying to reuse a query that already exists

Comment: you could use a Min() or Max() as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29399630/1275832