# Select one of each group by date using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
I have a table like this 
+----+----------+------------+
| se | FKMember |  Expdate   |
+----+----------+------------+
|  0 |     1    | 2019-03-01 |
|  1 |     3    | 2019-03-07 |
|  2 |     2    | 2019-01-01 |
|  3 |     1    | 2019-04-01 |
|  4 |     3    | 2019-09-07 |
|  5 |     1    | 2019-05-01 |
+----+-----------------------+
```

I want to return one row , this row contain Max date for member

i need the result should be

```
+----+----------+------------+
| s. | FKMember |  Expdate   |
+----+----------+------------+
|  2 |     2    | 2019-01-01 |
|  4 |     3    | 2019-09-07 |
|  5 |     1    | 2019-05-01 |
+----+-----------------------+
```

I using this code , but it return one row , this row contain max date
What should I do to get a row for each member
..................................................................................................................................................

```
private void R2()
     
         int? MemberIDAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(MemberID) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(MemberID);
         int? MainPackageCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(MainPackageCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(MainPackageCode);
         int? SubPackageCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(SubPackageCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(SubPackageCode);
         int? PackageTypeCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PackageTypeCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(PackageTypeCode);
         int? PackageCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PackageCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(PackageCode);
         int? CorporateCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(CorporateCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(CorporateCode);
         int? SalesCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(SalesCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(SalesCode);
         int? TrainerCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TrainerCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(TrainerCode);
         int? RelationshipCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelationshipCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(RelationshipCode);
         int? NationalityCodeAsInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(NationalityCode) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(NationalityCode);
         bool? GenderAsBool = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Gender.ToString()) ? null : (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(Gender);
         DateTime? StartDatePackageFromAsDate = StartDatePackageFrom == string.Empty ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(StartDatePackageFrom);
         DateTime? StartDatePackageToAsDate = StartDatePackageTo == string.Empty ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(StartDatePackageTo);
         DateTime? EndDatePackageFromAsDate = EndDatePackageFrom == string.Empty ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(EndDatePackageFrom);
         DateTime? EndDatePackageToAsDate = EndDatePackageTo == string.Empty ? null : (DateTime?)Convert.ToDateTime(EndDatePackageTo);

         using (var dbcontext = new database.GymEntities())
         {
             var Employee_Data = dbcontext
                              .VPackageForMembers

                              .Where(u => (MemberIDAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKMemberID == MemberIDAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (MainPackageCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKMainPakage == MainPackageCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (SubPackageCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKSubPackage == SubPackageCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (PackageTypeCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKPackageType == PackageTypeCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (PackageCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKPackage == PackageCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (CorporateCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKCorporate == CorporateCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (SalesCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKSalesPerson == SalesCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (TrainerCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKTrainer == TrainerCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (RelationshipCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKRelationShip == RelationshipCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (NationalityCodeAsInt == null) ? true : u.FKRelationShip == NationalityCodeAsInt)
                              .Where(u => (GenderAsBool == null) ? true : u.Gender == GenderAsBool)
                              .Where(u => (StartDatePackageFromAsDate == null) ? true : u.StartDate >= StartDatePackageFromAsDate && u.StartDate <= StartDatePackageToAsDate)
                              .Where(u => (EndDatePackageFromAsDate == null) ? true : u.ExpDate >= EndDatePackageFromAsDate && u.ExpDate <= EndDatePackageToAsDate)
                              .OrderByDescending (u=> u.ExpDate)
                              .Take(1)
                              .Select(u => new
                              {
                                  
                                  u.FKMemberID,
                                  u.MemberEnglishName,
                                  u.MainPackageEnglishName,
                                  u.SubPackageEnglishName,
                                  u.PackageTypeEnglishName,
                                  u.PackageEnglishName,
                                  u.ExpDate,
                                  u.PhoneNo1
                              }
                              )                                
                              .ToList();

             datasource = new ReportDataSource("MemberExpireData", Employee_Data);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to see some tutorials on grouping using LINQ. and they might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework Group By with Max Date and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399430/entity-framework-group-by-with-max-date-and-count) ALSO do not use Where like this. EF is pretty stupid and ALL this conditions will flatten your performance when SQL server buildhis execution plan. Event if they are all NULL.

Comment: i need to allow user choose where condition how can refactoring this in a better way ??? @eocron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For re-factoring the Where conditions:

```
using (var dbcontext = new database.GymEntities())
{
    var query = dbcontext.VPackageForMembers.AsQueryable();
    if (memberIDAsInt.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(u => u.FKMemberID == memberIDAsInt);
    if (mainPackageCodeAsInt.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(u => u.FKMainPackage == mainPackageCodeAsInt);
    // ...

    var employeeData = query.OrderByDescending(u=> u.ExpDate)
        .Take(1)
        .Select(u => new
        {
            u.FKMemberID,
            u.MemberEnglishName,
            u.MainPackageEnglishName,
            u.SubPackageEnglishName,
            u.PackageTypeEnglishName,
            u.PackageEnglishName,
            u.ExpDate,
            u.PhoneNo1
        }).ToList();
    datasource = new ReportDataSource("MemberExpireData", employeeData);
}
```

By doing the comparisons in code you simplify the generated SQL to only include conditions that actually need to be provided.

Next, to do the grouping by FK:

```
    var employeeData = query
        .Select(g => new
        {
            u.FKMemberID,
            u.MemberEnglishName,
            u.MainPackageEnglishName,
            u.SubPackageEnglishName,
            u.PackageTypeEnglishName,
            u.PackageEnglishName,
            u.ExpDate,
            u.PhoneNo1
        }).GroupBy(u => u.FKMemberID)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(u => u.ExpDate).FirstOrDefault())
        .ToList();
```

The premise is to project your results /w Select and group by the desired value, in your case the FKMemberID. From the group you can then order your results and select the first value. Note that within the `Select` expression you need to use `FirstOrDefault` rather than `First`. `First` results in a Linq generation error, though it seems it should work as each group should contain at least 1 entry.

You should also consider adding pagination if your overall data volume could grow over time given searches like this could end up returning potentially large #s of results.